# How to control the size of an Android EditText object

Tags: android, eclipse, android-edittext

I have the following code based on the example shown at
[Android devloper website](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html#EditText)

```
final EditText idInput =  new EditText(this);
        idInput.setHeight(50);
        idInput.setWidth(winSize.x / 4);
        idInput.setHint("enter ID");
        idInput.setVisibility(0x00);
        idInput.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener()
        {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
            {
                // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
                if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
                    (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))
                {
                  // Perform action on key press
                  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, idInput.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  idInput.setVisibility(0x04);
                  return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

The code receives input from the edittext and shows it in a toast as expected.
My problem is that I can not control the size of the EditText. It fills my whole screen.
Is there a way of setting the size  of the TextView. I am not having any issue with other View object that I display.

(judging from the number of EditText questions on here is is not as simple as it should be)

Comment: try to use maxLength in xml. It can control the size of the edittext

Comment: when the edittext fills the whole screen, on focussed? or not focussed ?

Comment: @Rosalie, I have tried .setmaxWidth and .setmaxHeight without success. I have no XML for this activity.

Comment: @Yugandhar, when it is first made visible in fills the screen. When I set it invisible it disappears.

Comment: ok. Did you try setMaxEms() or setMinEms() ?

Comment: @Rosalie, no, as soon as I can find out what an Ems is I will try it.

Comment: How are you actually displaying this view?  What does the rest of the code in your Activity look like? Because if you are simply calling `setContentView(idInput)` inside of an `Activity` somewhere you will have no chance of resizing the view without supplying some layout parameters first.

Comment: OK, the answer supplied by Devunwired solved the problem. It also means that most comments from others will also apply, his was the enabling point. The secret LayoutParams are all important ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a hunch that the code surrounding your example looks something like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final EditText idInput =  new EditText(this);
    idInput.setHeight(50);
    idInput.setWidth(winSize.x / 4);
    idInput.setHint("enter ID");
    idInput.setVisibility(0x00);
    idInput.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener()
    {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
        {
            // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
                (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))
            {
              // Perform action on key press
              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, idInput.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              idInput.setVisibility(0x04);
              return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    setContentView(idInput);
}
```

If so, your problem is that you cannot just attach a view directly to an Activity window without supplying `LayoutParams` as well.  Otherwise, it adds in `FILL_PARENT` for both the layout width and height when attaching to the window and forces the view to fill the content space.

If you modify the last line to something like this:

```
setContentView(idInput, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

You will see the `EditText` drop down to a more normal size and your adjustments on height/width will actually start to take effect.  When layouts are coded in XML, this requirement is often forgotten since most people always use a root layout that fills the screen and habitually, apply `layout_width` and `layout_height` to everything else.

HTH

Comment: You're a genius!   I used main.addView(idInput, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));  and the EditText appears correct size top left.  Using setContentView() hides my current view which I did not want.  Where did you find the LayoutParams details?

Comment: Are there LayoutParams to place the EditText where you want it?

Comment: @Neil, from the code you mentioned it sounds like you do have at least one layout manager in your application, do you know which one (LinearLayout, FrameLayout, etc.)?  Reason being the answer to your question "Are there LayoutParams to do X?" depends on the layout you are using.  Perhaps you could post the entire section of code you are using to construct views and attach them to the Activity in your question.  Also, you may benefit from giving this item in the SDK Docs a read: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

Comment: Just read the description of FrameLayout and it tells me I can't do what I have been doing! I am using it because the AbsoluteLayout is deprecated and no other Layout seems to provide what I need. I have 1000 lines of code that works but http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html tells me I can't do it.

Comment: As a side note the reference documentation at developer.android.com would be the worst I have seen in my 35 years of engineering. Very strange coming from google who are usually pretty good.

Comment: Case in point - from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html
"All child elements of the FrameLayout are pinned to the top left corner of the screen; you cannot specify a different location for a child view."
and from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html
"You can, however, add multiple children to a FrameLayout and control their position within the FrameLayout by assigning gravity to each child"

Comment: You are correct that Android layout managers do not support absolute positions of elements, but rather relative positions.  It is bad design practice to use static position values in Android as the goal is to create UI that will scale and reorient to each different device size/resolution.  AbsoluteLayout was deprecated because it basically violates that principle.  The concept is very akin to liquid layouts in web design.  Hopefully you will be able to find a layout manager that can accomodate your needs.  Keep in mind they can be nested to create more complex layouts.  Cheers.

Comment: @ Devunwired, I understand what you are saying. Problem is that to do what I am doing with the preferred Layouts it turns a simple requirement into a complex solution. In my view absolute positioning does not equate to static positioning. My code scales everything based on the screen size. Maybe Android has the tools, I found it easier to write the code than find the tools.

Answer (score 0):

Try using setMaxWidth(int)

```
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setMaxWidth(int)
```

Comment: I had tried that and it made no difference. The documentation clearly says it should.

Answer (score 0):

Check inside this function

```
 idInput.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener()
    {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
        {
            // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
                (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))
            {
              // Perform action on key press
              check her 
              if(idInput.getText().tostring.length<=MaximumLength Define by you)

              return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

**There is dynamic method also present**

```
        ImageView img1=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
    img1.setMaxHeight(100);
    img1.setMaxWidth(100);
```

Comment: @TofeeqAhmed, thanks but it is not the content length that is my problem it is the overall size of the view object.

Comment: if you gave fix size like width=100,height=100,and singleline=true.Check it once please

Comment: No luck, looks like I am going to have to try the xml method. Not happy about it but what can you do?

Comment: I have edited my answer check now.i have show for Imageview.For EditText same can be used

Comment: I am wondering if it somehow related specifically to the EditText. I have no problem with other View objects.

Comment: i did not get your above point.This is present for EditText also

Answer (score 0):

You can override the onMeasure function (in your custom view). Its the method which is called when the control's parent is laying its child control. Hv a look below...

```
@override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
{
int yourExpWidth = someoperation(widthMeasureSpec);
int yourExpHeight = someoperation(heightMeasureSpec);

setMeasuredDimension(yourExpWidth ,yourExpHeight );

}
```

Or you can keep your EditText static by defining it in the Activity's XML. And then using it in your program using findViewById(R.id.Editet)

Answer (score 0):

It is use to control the size of the EditTextView.

editText.setLines(int lines);